# What's the difference between these three Task Continuations?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, continuations

I have these two scenarios, but I don't understand why things are happening as they do:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***Starting T1");
        //run two tasks sequentially
        Task t = FirstTask().ContinueWith(_ => SecondTask(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        //register succeded and faulted continuations
        t.ContinueWith(_ => Completion(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        t.ContinueWith(_ => Faulted(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("***Starting T2");
        Task t2 = FirstTask().ContinueWith(_ => FaultTask(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        t2.ContinueWith(_ => Completion(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        t2.ContinueWith(_ => Faulted(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("***Starting T3");
        Task t3 = FirstTask().ContinueWith(ant => ant.ContinueWith(_ => FaultTask(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion));
        t3.ContinueWith(_ => Completion(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
        t3.ContinueWith(_ => Faulted(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static Task FirstTask()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task 1");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        });
    }

    private static Task SecondTask()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task 2");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        });
    }

    private static Task FaultTask()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Throw...");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            throw new ArgumentException();
        });
    }

    private static void Completion()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Complete");
    }

    private static void Faulted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Faulted");
    }
```

In case 1, things are ran as expected. However, if the `Sleep()` in `FirstTask()` is removed, there is no guarantee the tasks are run in order.

In case 2, The `Faulted()` handler is not run. I would expect this to occur since there is an unhandled exception.

In case 3, the exception is thrown after the `Complete()` handler is run. I am confused as to why this ordering has occurred.

Basically I want to be able to chain as many tasks as I want and for them to run in order after the previous one finished. Once I have created the chain, I will then show a wait form and register continuations for `OnlyOnRanToCompletion`, `OnlyOnCancelled`, `OnlyOnFaulted` into the final task (read: after all have finished) to close the form - displaying success or error.

Is this where MSDN is referring to those options that are not available for multi task continuations?

Comment: Both tasks [ran to completion](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dul82Y). Voting to close as can't reproduce. Will retract once you update the question with code which can reproduce the problem. I suspect your original code will have some Continuation flags set which you're not showing us.

Comment: Still your code won't show the described behavior. Please run the code and test yourself before posting it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the code required to demonstrate the issue such that I can copy-and-paste the code into a console app and it will run? Currently the first task won't even compile.

Comment: @Simon, whenever you call `Task.Run()`, you task is already started. So, for example, in the first line of code you're starting both tasks simultaneously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return type on `t` and `t2` are `Task<Task>` not just a Task.  T3 is a `Task<Task<Task>>`.  To get the desired behavior, you should be able to [Unwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the tasks which will give you a task that represents the entire operation (read the docs for more info):

```
Console.WriteLine("***Starting T1");
//run two tasks sequentially
Task<Task> t = FirstTask().ContinueWith(_ => SecondTask(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

//register succeded and faulted continuations
t.Unwrap().ContinueWith(_ => Completion(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
t.Unwrap().ContinueWith(_ => Faulted(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("***Starting T2");

Task<Task> t2 = FirstTask().ContinueWith(_ => FaultTask(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
t2.Unwrap().ContinueWith(_ => Completion(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
t2.Unwrap().ContinueWith(_ => Faulted(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I would recommend looking into using the async/await pattern where possible, as it makes dealing with tasks like these much easier.

Comment: thanks, yes i understand normally I can use: `await t1; await t2; await t3;`, but then checking task completion status is a little more cumbersome

Comment: @Simon, Why do you consider it more cumbersome? It is certainly more readable. Most likely, whatever you are considering more cumbersome with the async/await approach could be fixed by a helper method or two.

Comment: The solution to only perform `t2` if the first ran successfully, or only run `t3` if the first faulted is IMO less readable. you have to hold a ref to the `Task` and then perform an `if`